# Need some help here in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to run my app but they give me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4DJx.png), how can I fix it

Comment: print stack here, error is cut on screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Simply do one thing just Cache Invalidate / Restart.. 
you can Find this option in file..